# Safari Mac missing tab

Tags: mac, safari, big-sur

I'm on the latest version of Big Sur and Safari and I get this strange bug very often. The tabs split off like this and there is a missing one in the middle. I can only click on these three tabs when I have four tabs open. This bug happens no matter how many tabs I have open[image]

Comment: will probably stop with safari 15.1 in a few weeks, likely just a bug

Comment: me too. sometimes if I close a tab before the gap, I can access the hidden one. likely a bug that will be fixed soon (amazed they didn't spot it during beta testing though)